# Using parallel processors with the Amelia package

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I want to create multiple data sets with Amelia, but the data set is large so it takes a long time.  As a result, I'm trying to run the multiple imputation with parallel processors in Windows. Could someone can help me?

```
library(Amelia)
library(parallel)
detectCores(all.tests = FALSE, logical = TRUE)
[1] 4

mi <- amelia(impute, m=10, 
             idvars=c("ID","SCHL","SEX","WAVE", "YEAR"), 
             parallel=c("snow"), cl=cluster(c("localhost")))
```

I don't know how to write up this command.

Comment: Does your code work? Do you get an error?

Comment: Yes, It works. But the speed of processing is the same as that without parallel.

Comment: @user2702330 - did my answer work out for you? If so, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the multicore package instead. Works for me:

```
library(Amelia)
library(multicore)

mi <- amelia(impute, m=10, 
             idvars=c("ID","SCHL","SEX","WAVE", "YEAR"), 
             parallel = "multicore" , ncpus = 4)
```

In the comments, you say that your posted code "works", but that execution time is the same when not using the parallel option. Perhaps your data set is relatively small and does not benefit from being split?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Windows machine, then you need to set `parallel` option to `snow`. You are doing this correctly. The `multicore` option is used for Linux systems. The issue with your code is that you did not specify `ncpus` argument. Therefore, the number of cpus used is set to 1 as default setting, which causes it to run about the same duration as serial running. So, simply add `ncpus = 4` in your `amelia` function and it should work:

```
mi <- amelia(impute, m=10, 
             idvars=c("ID","SCHL","SEX","WAVE", "YEAR"), 
             parallel=c("snow"), cl=cluster(c("localhost")), ncpus = 4)
```

Additionally, if you are using panel data don't forget to set `ts` and `cs` arguments for the time series and cross section variables in your dataset to obtain more accurate imputations. Otherwise, all imputations will assume homogeneity and continuity across the observations.